# Regular expression Notepad++ multiple replace?

Tags: regex, search, replace

Is there a way to perform multiple search and replace using Regular expresion?
I have strings:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

across the plain text, and I want to replace them

```
aaa to replace with ddd
bbb to replace with eee
ccc to replace with fff
```

Is there a regular expression to do that at once, using one single regex?

I am using Notepad++

Comment: record a macro of 3 replacements?

Comment: The only way would to be to get the character code, increment it by 3 and then set that once you had the match.  This could be done with regex and some custom code, but not with straight regex in Notepad++, as regex doesn't offer anything like incrementing character code.

Comment: There is no way to use multiple replacement strings in a literal form. You need to use 3 separate search and replace operations.

Answer (score 7):

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11385/how-to-multi-replace

The general syntax is:

Find: `(FindA)|(FindB)|(FindC)...`
Replace: `(?1ReplaceA)(?2ReplaceB)(?3ReplaceC)...`

**Notes:** Be sure that the *Regular expression* search mode is *checked*

For instance:

- Find what: `(aaa)|(ccc)|(eee)|(123)`
- Replace with: `(?1bbb)(?2ddd)(?3fff)(?{4}456)`

gives:

- The string `aaa` is changed into `bbb`
- The string `ccc` is changed into `ddd`
- The string `eee` is changed into `fff`
- The string `123` is changed into `456`